# Group By in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Having "player" nodes in a Neo4j instance, I am interested to find all players that have the same name and a different shirt number. Basically a SQL group BY of player name and player jersey number.

Any tips?

thanks

Comment: Can you try creating sample here http://console.neo4j.org/ ?

Comment: I have tried and failed. I have a node called player that has name and tshirt_number properties. I just want a list of all players with same name and different tshirt numbers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The aggregation you want can be achieved by [collect](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/query-aggregation.html#aggregation-collect).

```
 START n = node(*) 
 RETURN n.name, collect(n.tshirt_number)
```

I made a small example graph:

http://console.neo4j.org/r/1vfeug

Comment: The link is no longer valid - I think it now points to a different graph